# ios on first segue next view elements not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new to iOS development want to set textlabel of next view . But it is set after the first visit of the view i.e, when I visit again.

Please correct me. Below is the code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "postSegue"){
        let nextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! ShareViewController)
        nextViewController.username = self.user_id
        nextViewController.dateTime = self.user_email
    }
}
```

Next View controller

```
var username = String()
var dateTime = String()
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateTimeLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
 self.usernameLabel.text = self.username
 self.dateTimeLabel.text = self.dateTime
}
```

Comment: With that code you will be setting username and dateTime of the nextViewController everytime a segue with id="postSegue" is performed. Your code looks OK

Comment: even checked with breakpoints, 1st breakpoint on prepare for sgue and next on other view viewdidload method both are working but TextLables are not set for the first time.

Comment: Just check the values of self.username and self.dateTime on ViewDidLoad, they should be correct, if your labels are not showing it that must be another issue.

Comment: set break point and make sure that the        let nextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! ShareViewController)
        nextViewController.username = self.user_id
        nextViewController.dateTime = self.user_email codes are executed

Comment: @JasonNam yeah checked that as i metioned in above comment all variables are fetched at break points.